# Sharing and iOS versions in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter, ios6

I am making an application that outputs text and would like to give the users the option to share this text on twitter and/or Facebook..... I know that iOS6 is linked with twitter and Facebook. but what would happen if an user that has iOS 5.1 for example installs that application? I guess I am trying to see if I should use ios6 and the built in sharing features or ios5 and use sharekit to share on twitter and facebook.
My other question that is also related.

If I build my application in xcode with ios6 will users with ios5 installed still be able to install this application? what would then happen to the features that are only in ios6 like sharing?
Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your application's target to iOS 6, users operating on previous iOS versions will not be able to install it. Also, if you set the target to iOS 5 for example, you will not have the facebook native facebook integration available. So, in my opinion, you should set the target for iOS 5, set the facebook framework as optional and when launching the application, check what iOS version it's running on. If it is not iOS 6, use shareKit.

Comment: Sharekit just for facebook? He can use facebook sdk instead. Twitter was included on iOS5, so it's safe to use.

Comment: Good point. However, the question was also about sharekit, so i went along with it. Also, I think that implementing sharekit is easier than the facebook sdk...

Comment: Thanks @AndreiFilip So let me just check I understood correctly. I set the target for iOS5, check what version the user has, if the user has ios6 if not i use sharekit.. my only remaining question would be can i still use the same share button in ios5 even if twitter is native and i implemented facebook with sharekit?

Comment: yeah...in it's action method first check if it is ios5/6. You just have to do an if/else to see which you should use...